# Remove '.png' from string in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Basically I have a column in SQL Server that has icon image names

It's kind of like

```
ICON
------------
Icon001
Icon002.png
Icon003.png
Icon004.png
Icon005
Icon006.png
Icon007.png
```

I'm trying to figure out how I can write a script to remove all of the `.png` from the ones that have it

I have tried

```
Update [dbo].[screen].[icon] 
set ICON = ICON - '%.png%' 
where ICON LIKE '%.png%'
```

But that doesn't work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Hint: [`REPLACE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) and of course research on [previous related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+remove+part+of+string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
... set ICON=LEFT(icon, LEN(icon)-4 ) where ICON like '%.png'
```

Comment: why not? what if one of the records is `image.png.png`? replace'll kill both .png's

Comment: I stand corrected. It's an unlikely occasion, but it could happen.

Comment: yep, unlike, but I've learned to not trust in "unlikely". as the old statement goes: million-to-one-chances have a 50:50 chance of occuring: either they do, or they don't.

Answer (score 2):

```
...SET ICON = REPLACE(ICON, '.png','')
```

Should do the trick

Comment: +1 I like this better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
UPDATE icon SET icon = LEFT(icon, CHARINDEX('.png', icon) - 1) WHERE icon LIKE '%.png%'
```

[A demo of something](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86f7f/2)

Comment: what about a malformed filename like `image.png.gif.png`?

Comment: @MarcB Out of scope of the question.